# Does collection assigned by another collection will grow up in memory

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> mylist= new List<string>();
        mylist.Add("a");
        mylist.Add("b");
        mylist.Add("c");


        B b = new B(mylist);
        b.Add();
        Console.WriteLine(mylist.Count.ToString()); //Output 4


    }
}

class B
{
    public List<string> mylist2 { get; set; }
    public B(List<string> lsarg)
    {
        mylist2 = new List<string>(); //new allocate new location?
        mylist2 = lsarg;
    }
    public void Add()
    {
        mylist2.Add("hi");
    }
}
```

I understand that in B class contructor I m not copiying the lsarg list, thats why in line

```
mylist2=lsarg;
```

myList2 and lsarg is same list.
My question is, if I add mylist list new items does mylist2 in B object will grow up? I mean it will grow up in memory for B object?

Comment: Yes and no: `myList` and `myList2` both point to the same list in memory. Your `mylist2 = new List<string>();` does nothing, because you overwrite that value in the next line, and the new list is thrown away.

Comment: To prove it, try `Console.WriteLine(mylist.Count);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both of your variable `mulist` and `mylist2` point to the same reference of `List<>`.

`mylist` and `mylist2` are only (32|64)bit memory pointers, which points to a location where the actual `List<>` object is stored.

This is the difference between **Value** types and **Reference** types.

`List<>` is a reference type.

e.g.

```
List<string> mylist= new List<string>();
```

could be explained like this;

```
List<string> mylist;
// Creates a new variable mylist at location (0x1) which points to a List<string> (currently null)

mylist = new List<string>();
// Creates a new List<String> in memory location A
// and assigns variable mylist (0x1) to (0xA) which is where this new list is located
```

Then when you construct B:

```
new B(mylist);
// Calls constructor of B passing in the same reference that mylist holds. (0xA)
```

And inside constructor of B

```
List<string>() mylist2;
// Creates a new variable mylist2 at location 2 which points to a List<string> (currently null)

mylist2 = new List<string>(); 
// Creates a new List<String> in memory location B
// and assigns variable mylist (0x2) to (0xB) which is where this new list is located

mylist2 = lsarg;
// Assigns the passed in reference (0xA) to mylist2 (0x2), therefore pointing to the same place.
// Add this point the previous created list (0xB) no longer has any pointers to it.
// and will get Garbage Collected once GC runs.
```

Your memory would look something like this:

```
Location    Size    Value
[0x1]       32      [0xA] <-- Pointer
[0x2]       32      [0xA] <-- Pointer   
[...]
[0xA]       x       List<string>
[0xB]               List<string> <-- This has no pointer anymore, will get GC'ed
```

Comment: Note that value types don't "grow up in memory on assignment" too because they always take the same amount of memory...